# Intercept browser tab by name

Tags: javascript

Once I open a new browser tab, how do I tell JavaScript to execute whatever code comes next in this newly opened tab, instead of the first one?

Lets say I want to automate Google search: when user presses a button in one tab, a new tab is opened that navigates to Google page, and the search is then performed in this new tab.

```
window.open("https://www.google.com");
//~here I need to intercept the new tab (preferably by tab name) and execute some_other_function in it 
new_tab.onload = function() {some_other_function};
```

Comment: In the case of opening/performing a Google search: `window.open('https://www.google.com/search?search+terms+here')`, though this takes advantage of the GET request, and has no bearing on the question itself.

Comment: Yes, the Google search is only a simplified example of what I am trying to achieve. I won't be able to use query string parameters.

Answer (score 1):

the below code doesn't works in here. so you can check in the chrome console or in your application.

**Note** : change the script source with your script file.

you can create the script tag and add the script src, and append it to the head of the document of the new tab.

```js
var newWindow = window.open('');
newWindow.document.head.innerHTML = '<title>Hi</title></head>';

var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
scriptElement.textContent = "alert('JS is running');";
scriptElement.src = "/js/sample.js"
newWindow.document.head.appendChild(scriptElement);
```